# Read private key from apache SSL_CLIENT_CERT in java

Tags: java, apache, client-certificates

I've an apache protected with client authentication like this:

```
SSLCACertificateFile "..."
<Location ~ "...">
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 10
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT ""
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY ""

    # add whatever SSL_* variables needed to pass to web application
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s"
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY "%{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}s"
</Location>
```

I can read the content of header variable *SSL_CLIENT_CERT* in my Servlet via

```
String sslFromheader = httpServletRequest.getHeader( "SSL_CLIENT_CERT" );
```

But it seems that there is no section with *-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----* only the part

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----...-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

is provided in *sslFromheader*.

Is there anything wrong with my configuration/setup or is this still not possible and *"%{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}s"* contains not the whole client certificate?